# Grails service logging does not initialize

Tags: grails

The only way I can get the logging to work in my service is to add this to my service:

```
class MyService {
def log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass())
...
```

My log4j settings in Config.groovy:

```
log4j = {

    PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout("%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n")


    debug   'grails.app.controllers',
            'grails.app.controller',
            'grails.app.domain',
            'grails.app.service',
            'grails.app.filters',
            'com.mycompany'
//            'org.springframework.security'
            'org.hibernate.SQL'

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

    appenders {
        appender new org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender(name: "console",
                threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG,
                layout: patternLayout
        )
    }
    root {
        error 'stdout'
        additivity = true
    }
}
```

I would have thought the logging would work in a service without having to add def log... at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grails.app.service` should be `grails.app.services`. This changed in version 2.0.

You can easily find out the logger name in an artifact by adding

```
println log.name
```

to a test method and calling it.

Comment: Yep, a plural services fixed everything.